# garantizar vs asegurar

Tags: sinónimos

Según el DLE de la RAE, "[asegurar](https://dle.rae.es/asegurar)" puede significar:

1. vtr. Hacer que alguien o algo queden seguros o firmes. Ej: Asegurar la alcayata en la pared. Asegurar al niño en la sillita de paseo.
2. vtr. Decir algo con seguridad y sin duda. Ej: Te aseguro que me las pagará.
3. vprnl. Confirmar o aseverar la realidad o certeza de algo. Ej: ¿Me asegura que no hay riesgo?  Asegúrate DE cerrar bien la puerta.
4. vtr. Preservar o resguardar de daño a alguien o algo. Ej: Asegurar la casa con alarmas antirrobo.
5. vtr. Hacer que algo quede seguro o garantizado. Ej: Asegurar la compra de la casa mediante una señal.
6. vtr. Hacer un contrato de seguro para cubrir los daños que puedan sufrir alguien o algo. Ej: Asegurar una finca.

"[garantizar](https://dle.rae.es/garantizar)" es definido como "dar garantía". "[garantía](https://dle.rae.es/garant%C3%ADa)" puede significar:

1. sf. Efecto de afianzar lo estipulado.
2. sf. Fianza, prenda.
3. sf. Cosa que asegura y protege contra algún riesgo o necesidad.
4. sf. Seguridad o certeza que se tiene sobre algo. Ej: Lo hizo con la garantía de que no se producirán complicaciones.
5. sf. Compromiso temporal del fabricante o vendedor, por el que se obliga a reparar gratuitamente algo vendido en caso de avería.
6. sf. Documento de garantía de un producto.

Es correcto decir que "asegurar" e "garantizar" son sinónimos en las definiciones 2, 3, 4, 5 e 6 de "asegurar" ? ¿Las frases/expresiones de abajo son correctas y usuales?

- Te garantizo que me las pagará.
- ¿Me garantizas que no hay riesgo? Garantizate de cerrar bien la puerta.
- Garantizar la casa con alarmas antirrobo.
- Garantizar la compra de la casa mediante una señal.
- Garantizar una finca.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Te garantizo que me las pagará. CORRECTA
- ¿Me garantizas que no hay riesgo? Garantizate de cerrar bien la puerta.

Sólo "asegurar" puede usarse en forma pronominal, por lo que debe decirse: Asegúrate de cerrar bien la puerta.

- Garantizar la casa con alarmas antirrobo. (Debe usarse otro verbo, como "proteger")
- Garantizar la compra de la casa mediante una seña. CORRECTA
- Garantizar una finca. (Si se refiere a cubrir los riesgos con un seguro, debe usarse "asegurar". "garantizar" sólo funcionaría si se contrae una deuda, por ejemplo: garantizar la compra de una finca)